# WPF - OnDrop event blocks drag and dropping into Model Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dialog

In my WPF application I have a MainWindow and a Dialog.
When the OnDrop event inside the MainWindow is fired, it opens the Dialog.
The Dialog, also has an OnDrop event which can never be fired, as the MainWindow's OnDrop event is still active and blocks any other dragging and dropping.

How can I open the Dialog from the MainWindow's OnDrop event and then allow users to Drag and Drop data into the Dialog?

**MainWindow XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="DialogOpener.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        AllowDrop="True">
    <Label Background="Blue"
           FontSize="54" 
           Content="Main Window" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow Back Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDrop(e);
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog()
            {
                Owner = this
            };

            bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            if(result.HasValue && (bool)result)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Positive Result!!!");
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Dialog XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DialogOpener.Dialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        AllowDrop="True"
        Title="Dialog" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Label  Background="Red" FontSize="54"
                Content="Dialog"
                AllowDrop="True" />
</Window>
```

Dialog Back Code

```
public partial class Dialog : Window
    {
        public Dialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDrop(e);
            Debug.WriteLine("Dropped Content Into Dialog!!!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you intend to allow the user to drag/drop something different, or should it be the same thing the user originally dragged/dropped that you want to get into the dialog?

Comment: It would be something different. 
For example, the object they drop into the MainWindow could be an image from the file explorer. Then into the Dialog, it could be a completly different image from the file explorer or data from an external application. It would never be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dispatcher to open the dialog *after* the event handler has completed:

```
protected override void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDrop(e);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog()
        {
            Owner = this
        };

        bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result.HasValue && (bool)result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Positive Result!!!");
        }
    }));

    e.Handled = true;
}
```